# Is it possible to install a "For Purchase" package using apt-get?

Tags: apt

Do I have to use the Software Center to install a non-free package?

1. Can I make a purchase using apt-get?
2. How about if already made the purchase and I want to re-install the software. Can that be done with apt-get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Do I have to use the Software Center to install a non-free package?
```

Software Centre performs 2 distinct functions.  You can look up applications, and then install or remove then.  But, it is also invoked by default (as a GUI method) to install **.deb** (or Debian) files.

So NO, you could use some other method (there are many) or install a .deb package in a non-GUI manner.

```
 1. Can I make a purchase using apt-get?
```

Typically the 'software key' is separate from the software.  You only need a PPA to **apt-get** from.  You may then type in, install, or retrieve the software license (or key) to fully enable the software.

Some software in partially functioned without a license, others are fully functional for 30 or 60 days.

```
 2. How about if already made the purchase
and I want to re-install the software.
Can that be done with apt-get?
```

That simply depends on whether there is a PPA, and if the license is separate.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not sure, but I don't think so.
2. Yes, you can re-install previous purchases using apt-get.